# Github - Create repo by merging two

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Is it possible to create a Github repo by merging 2 Github repos such that the 2 repos keep updating themselves?

So, e.g.
There is a repo A by user X
Anothr repo B by user Y.
I am user Z, and feel that it is valuable to have an A+B distribution.

So I fork A. And I fork B.

Now, the first thing is I'd like A and B to automatically keep themselves updated based on their upstream repos. How do I do that?

And secondly, can I create an A+B repo such that the upstream changes made in both A and B are reflected in A+B?

Comment: You should have a look at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the first thing is I'd like A and B to automatically keep themselves updated based on their upstream repos. How do I do that?

This is how I do it (repeat for B):

1. Fork A
2. Clone my fork of A, e.g. `git clone git@github.com:ME/A`
3. Setup upstream, e.g. `cd A && git remote add upstream git@github.com:ORG/A`

When I want to update my fork I do `git fetch --all`, which will update my local repo with changes to any of the remotes, in this case my fork and the original repository.

> And secondly, can I create an A+B repo such that the upstream changes made in both A and B are reflected in A+B?

It depends. It's totally possible if A and B share some history. Say that A is the first repo, then B forks from that, then you can fork A and setup B as a remote. It's not possible if A and B are unrelated repositories.